# Can't connect to internet in safe mode

Tags: safe-mode

I've 512MB RAM, So i thought to boot in safe mode/safe mode with networking. but in windows xp, network cant be connected in safe mode.

And so, if u guys have any idea on altering msconfig or services.msc, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: What error do you receive while executing `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: with ping 8.8.8.8 in safe mode, its giving back as destination host unreachable

Comment: Please go to command prompt and type "ipconfig" without quotes and paste the reply in the question.

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\Kanoj>ipconfig  <br/>

Windows IP Configuration  <br/>

  
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:  <br/>
  
        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  <br/>
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3  <br/>
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0  <br/>
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1<br/>

Comment: awaiting for ur answer

Comment: I think if you can ping your modem (`ping 192.168.1.1`) the problem is your internet not windows!

Comment: ya, prblem is my modem is not getting connected, i googled a bit. windows xp wont give access to dialup connection in safe mode.

Comment: But i can connect to my modem in normal mode.. but i want to dig it in safe mode